# Using an if condition for a variable? in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am not sure how to call this scenario. Say i have this variable

```
let text: String?
```

How can it be coded such that my if condition would be something like this:

```
if (text == nil || Float(text) > 0) {
    print("i am in")
}
```

I keep getting No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: its `nil` not nill

Comment: yes. you are right. typo. will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here:

1. text is a `String?` and therefore it needs to be unwrapped to pass it to `Float()`
2. `Float()` returns an optional, this also should be unwrapped to be used with the `>` operator.

I would avoid force unwrapping, you can do something like:

```
let text: String? = nil

if let textString = text, let number = Float(textString)  {
    if number > 0 {
        print("I am in")
    }
    else {
        print("I am out")
    }
}
else {
    print("I am in")
}
```

Comment: This results in `”I am in”` when text is `”hello”` which is incorrect. Move the conversion to `Float` to the inner `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Two additional things must be done:

1. After your check if `text` is `nil` you must still unwrap the optional `text` to use it with the `Float()` constructor.  Here I’ve used a *forced unwrap* `!` which in general is dangerous, but we know at this point `text` cannot be `nil` due to the first test. If `text` is `nil`, the `||` uses *short-circuit evaluation* to return *true* without executing the right side.
2. Next, `Float(text!)` returns a `Float?` because that text might not convert to a valid `Float`.  In order to unwrap that I’ve used the *nil-coalescing operator* `??` to unwrap the `Float` value or use `0` if the value is `nil`.

   ```
   if text == nil || Float(text!) ?? 0 > 0 {
       print("i am in")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, looks like you want to check if text != nil then if text is number check if text > 0

Because in here you have optional String so you should have a specific to check if string text not nil. Then check if it is number.
Code will be like this

```swift
extension String  {
    var isNumber: Bool {
        return Double(self) != nil
    }
}
```

Then combine to your condition

```swift
if text == nil || (text!.isNumber && Float(text!)! > 0) {
    print("i am in")
}
```

The result will be like this

```swift
let text: String? = "2.0" // i am in
let text: String? = nil // i am in
let text: String? = "-1.0" // nothing print
```

Answer (score 1):

text is an optional

```
if (text == nil) || Float(text ?? "") ?? 0 > 0 {
    print("i am in")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I am just starting with Swift. I find these are all correct.